# DNAME Functionality Using CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver, cname-record, namecheap

I have a simple name server with namecheap, however the company I host Teamspeak with redirects to have an IP with Teamspeak's default port. So the IP they give me actually looks like this instead, test.Domain.com and I want to redirect that to ts.MyDomain.com. This can be easily done with DNAME however I do not have that capability with my name server. After looking around for a bit I found someone suggest that it was possible using a CNAME solution. Any Ideas?

[CNAME SUGGESTION](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/dname.html)

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. They gave you something that links to the teamspeak server. Why would you want to make it link to something else? And if so, what?

Comment: @David RE: why, it's basically cosmetics/personalization. Fairly legitimate.

Comment: @AndrewB Cosmetics is about what you point to something, not about what you point something to. He wants to redirect the name they gave him to something else, which is a "what it goes to" thing, not a "what goes to it" thing. At least, that's how I read the question.

Comment: @David The wording is confusing (and reversed), but based on the use case there's reasonable confidence that this is an attempt to use his personal domain with an application that leverages multiple `SRV` records under a subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DNAME` record is used to synthesize *multiple* `CNAME` records. So long as you know all of the individual records you need to alias, then yes, `CNAME` alone will suffice.

That said, you need to understand the actual record that your client is trying to use. Please consult the documentation and make sure you understand all of the `SRV` records that you need to individually alias. I leave this as an exercise to the reader.